# Send file as a response not file path. How to Send xlsx file as a response in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have read data from mysqldb and write into xlsx file and stored into directory using xlsxwriter. Now i want to send a response as a xlsx file not file path. Can you please anyone help me to do this.

```
  filter_data = (('Shankar','100','Good'),('Sekar','20','Bad'),('Sugu','100','Good'))
  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('report.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
  for row, x in enumerate(filter_data):
    for col, y in enumerate(x):
      worksheet.write(row, col, str(y))
  workbook.close()
```

I want to send a response as a xlsx file in python. I tried like below

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.xlsx"'
return response
```

The above statement i have used. But am getting the following error
**didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Comment: can you post the whole view code?

Comment: See this [Simple Django class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_django_simple.html) example from the XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 0):

In the `HttpResponse` you should provide the content of the file you want to send to the user:

```
response = HttpResponse(content=content, content_type='application/ms-excel')
```

Where `content` is a file object or a bytesting of the content you would want to send to the user to download.

Comment: Yes i have seen this . But how do i get the content. I already stored the data in excel file. Can you please

Comment: If you have the file `report.xlsx` you can just open it with `open("report.xlsx", "rb")` and pass as the `content`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open("path/report.xlsx", "rb") as excel:
     data = excel.read()
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.xlsx"'
return response
```

Comment: I have tried this .. But am getting the above error which i mentioned. It's returned None. I did the same like this which you said

Comment: Are you reading the excel file and sending its content to the HttpResponse?

Comment: YEs. The same thing only i did which you said

Comment: try this `content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`